# Try not getting executed more than once in while(true) loop

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I am writing a simple part of a program where the user gives the year being born. The code is as follows:

```
while(true){
   try {
      year = input.nextInt();
      break;
   } catch (InputMismatchException mismatchException) {
       System.err.println("year of birth can only have numbers");
   }
}
```

So what happens is if i give a valid int (year is of type int) everything is ok. If i give a string like "hello" what i expected it to do is to get again inside try and ask me for a number after it has written the error message. 

Is my way of thinking wrong concerning try - catch statement?

Comment: Is the catch's message getting printed? Anything else printed? Btw, nextInt only advances the scanner if an int is found; if it's not, the next scanner is unchanged and will try to re-parse that string again next loop. You should use hasNextInt, followed by nextInt or just plain next() if you just want to advance the scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ( I guess input is java.util.Scanner):

```
while(input.hasNext()) {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
       year = input.nextInt();
       break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("year of birth can only have numbers");
        input.next();
    }
}
input.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this so you can get the next input, if you dont give a number:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
int year;
boolean repeat = true;
while(repeat){
try {
        repeat = false;
          year = input.nextInt();
       } catch (InputMismatchException mismatchException) {
           System.err.println("year of birth can only have numbers");
           input.next();
           repeat = true;
       }
}

System.out.println("DONE");
```

Comment: It's not a good habit to use exceptions as control flow. You should use hasNextInt instead.

Comment: Thats right - a better solution (not such dirty as mine ;) ) is the solution from Daniel Boncioaga - but my one is a solution too!